# How to modify "remember me" expired time in Laravel 5.2+?

Tags: laravel

After using `php artisan make:auth`, Laravel's "remember me" will remember the user indefinitely.

How to change that time? Like make it expire in 7 days?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Step 1

In `LoginController`, you'll see `use AuthenticatesUsers`.

Let's copy `protected function sendLoginResponse(Request $request)` from `AuthenticatesUsers` to `LoginController`.

### Step 2

We can change the cookie's expire time before server response to the browser. Let's add some code into `sendLoginResponse()` in `LoginController`. Like this

```
class LoginController extends Controller
{
    ...

    protected function sendLoginResponse(Request $request)
    {
        // set remember me expire time
        $rememberTokenExpireMinutes = 60;

        // first we need to get the "remember me" cookie's key, this key is generate by laravel randomly
        // it looks like: remember_web_59ba36addc2b2f9401580f014c7f58ea4e30989d
        $rememberTokenName = Auth::getRecallerName();

        // reset that cookie's expire time
        Cookie::queue($rememberTokenName, Cookie::get($rememberTokenName), $rememberTokenExpireMinutes);


        // the code below is just copy from AuthenticatesUsers
        $request->session()->regenerate();

        $this->clearLoginAttempts($request);

        return $this->authenticated($request, $this->guard()->user())
            ?: redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
    }
}
```

Comment: You can avoid having to paste code from AuthenticatesUsers, by specifying an alias for `use AuthenticatesUsers`, and then calling that implementation. E.g. `use AuthenticatesUsers { sendLoginResponse as baseSendLoginResponse; }`, and then in your implementation of sendLoginResponse you can finish it off with `return baseSendLoginResponse($request);`

Comment: When I use this code, it creates the cookie with correct expiration time, but if I delete the main laravel session cookie, then the remember cookie doesn't keep user logged in. It forces user to re-login for some reason.

Answer (score 4):

Use @Hexor has a problem, when user first login, you can't use
Cookie::get($rememberTokenName);
it's empty!

You should get cookie queue value first, then reset cookie expire time.

```
$rememberTokenExpireMinutes = 20;

// 首先获取 记住我 这个 Cookie 的名字, 这个名字一般是随机生成的,
// First, get remember me cookie name. This is randomly generated.
$rememberTokenName = \Auth::getRecallerName();

$cookieJar = $this->guard()->getCookieJar();

$cookieValue = $cookieJar->queued($rememberTokenName)->getValue();

$cookieJar->queue($rememberTokenName, $cookieValue, $rememberTokenExpireMinutes);

$jumpUrl = '/user/xxxx';

return $this->authenticated($request, $this->guard()->user())
    ?: redirect()->intended($jumpUrl);
```

Comment: This should be the right answer.  The select answer doesn't work when you delete the main session cookie, it doesn't utilize the remember me cookie for some reason. However, this one does it correctly. My guess is the way it get's cookie value is the key.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the remember me cookie duration by adding `'remember' => 43800 //(use minutes)` in the config in `config/auth.php`

Just change this:

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
],
```

to:

```
'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
            'remember' => 43800 // Set remember me duration here
        ],
    ],
```

Note: The 'remember' key is a mandatory keyword because it will be read by laravel in [`Illuminate\Auth\AuthManager`](https://laravel.com/api/9.x/Illuminate/Auth/AuthManager.html) namespace

Comment: This answer applies to Laravel 9+

Answer (score 0):

I know the question is old but I had a hard time getting a solution for Laravel 7.3, so I thought I should add what worked for me here.

In your App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController.php file, make the following changes

```
//Add this after namespace declaration
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

//Add this function to the class
protected function sendLoginResponse(Request $request)
    {
        $rememberTokenExpiresAt = 60*24*30; //expires in 30 days
        $rememberTokenCookieKey = $this->guard()->getRecallerName();
        $cookieJar = $this->guard()->getCookieJar();

  /* check if remember me token exists and then override it using the same name and value but different expiration time.
 
If you don't add the if condition, it will throw an error when user doesn't check the remember me box*/
        if ($cookieJar->queued($rememberTokenCookieKey)) {
            $cookieValue = $cookieJar->queued($rememberTokenCookieKey)->getValue();
            $cookieJar->queue($rememberTokenCookieKey, $cookieValue, $rememberTokenExpiresAt);
        }

        $request->session()->regenerate();

        $this->clearLoginAttempts($request);

        if ($response = $this->authenticated($request, $this->guard()->user())) {
            return $response;
        }

        return $request->wantsJson()
                    ? new JsonResponse([], 204)
                    : redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

in laravel 5.8

```
class CookiesJar.php

function forever($name, $value, $path = null, $domain = null, $secure = null, $httpOnly = true, $raw = false, $sameSite = null)

return $this->make($name, $value, 2628000, $path, $domain, $secure, $httpOnly, $raw, $sameSite);
```

change it into ,this

```
return $this->make($name, $value, 1440, $path, $domain, $secure, $httpOnly, $raw, $sameSite);
```

Comment: Downvoted because it is a really bad idea to edit vendor files. Imagine that you push your code to a remote repository, your vendor directory will normally be ignored and your team or colleagues will never get your edits. Or imagine you update a package, the files will be rewritten and your changes will be lost. Seriously don't do this.

Comment: @louisfischer it's not a problem so long as you automate the patching. We've had vendor patches in a laravel project for several years and it works just fine. You need to add that to your composer "post-update-cmd" and "post-install-cmd", of course.